# How to delete all shortcut (.lnk) files for a particular software from the machine?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, registry, advanced-installer

I am trying to delete all .lnk files from the sytem for a particular software. Is there anyway to delete all shorcuts using registry?

I have written a C# program which searches entire machine for a particular .lnk file and it deletes from the machine but I know this is not an eligant way and in this approach start menu shorcut is still pinned.

Can any one help me how to resolve this by generic way.

Here I am using Advanced Installer while uninstalling software script should delete all the shorcuts from the machine.

Comment: I think whatever way you go it will be a recursive search incase of manual shortcuts. Maybe these help you: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/7ce28a07-ebd4-480e-becc-4413ab17d4b8/find-and-delete-shortcuts-on-xp?forum=winserverpowershell, http://superuser.com/questions/194783/finding-all-shortcuts-to-a-file-application

Comment: The registry won't directly tell you anything about the location of .lnk files. The only way to be sure to get every possible file is to use your C# program. There is no generic way. Of course, you could always restrict your search to just those seen by a particular user. BTW Can you rewrite your last paragraph?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is open Command Prompt without Admin,

Type: `cd Desktop`*

Then type: `del *<NAME OF PROGRAM>*.lnk`*

*Commands are for Windows

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the Windows Scripting Host's ability to edit shortcut files. It's called CreateShortcut, but rest assured it can also open and modify them.

```
$Target = [RegEx]::Escape("C:\Program Files\Something\Application.exe") #Change this to the path to your executable
$wshShell = new-object -comobject WScript.Shell
get-childitem -path C:\ -filter *.lnk -recurse | foreach-object {
    $shortcut = $wshShell.CreateShortcut($_.FullName)
    If($shortcut.TargetPath -match $Target){$_.Delete()}
}
```

That scans the whole hard drive for shortcuts (*.LNK), and for each one it finds it opens up the properties of it, checks the target, and if it matches your executable path it deletes it.